# Adding external library to a LibGdx project

Tags: java, libgdx

I need to add this library https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers
 to my libgdx android project, can someone please tell me how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `compile 'me.everything:providers-android:1.0.1'` into your dependencies {} in root build.gradle and then "Sync Project with Gradle Files"

For more information here is an [official documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle).

Comment: And how do you know what to put? in that library it says it in readme file  but for example in this one https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/
where should i look for that? Thanks

Comment: For this particular project here is an instruction [page](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/releases), so the line you are looking for is `compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:1.2.2_139`. But general practice is to search in [maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/)